# Chromedriver switches --disable-popup-blocking Doesn't Work Using Ruby in Headless Mode

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I start my chromedriver like this in Ruby

```
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-notifications --start-maximized]
```

But, when I start using headless mode like below, it returns nothing.

```
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %W[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-notifications --disable-gpu --headless]
```

I need the switch `--disable-popup-blocking` in order to prevent the "Allow Location" popup on the website I am trying to access. It works if the chrome doesn't start in headless. But it doesn't work in headless mode. Is there any way to make it works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Preferences are not currently supported in Headless Mode. See Comment 7 in [this Chromium Bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775911#c7)