# How to disable popup blocker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Currently, I am facing an issue. If I visit the page with `headless: false` everything is fine. While `headless: true` the page detected that Popup Blocker is enabled so I can't continue with the remaining action.

Here is my browser config:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--disable-popup-blocking", "--allow-popups-during-page-unload"],
    headless: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
  });
  await page.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
  );
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  await page.setBypassCSP(true);
  await page.goto(URL);
```

Is there any way to disable the popup blocker?

Comment: I cant imagine that popup blocking is default on chrome. That is normally an addon right? What is the binary you are using? Is it your own browser? You should download a chrome binary for this.

Comment: @unflores I am using the built-in chromium

Comment: Looks like you enable two different arguments. Do you try enable or disable PopUp? Do you need that popup or you don't?

Comment: @kirill.z thanks for helping bro, this is actually a known chromium bug

Comment: @OysterD3 Please share that bug with me?

Comment: @kirill.z https://stackoverflow.com/a/47894218/6820538

Comment: @OysterD3 I experiment with PopUp Alerts and found an interesting thing, works for me with `headless: false` as a precondition of browser context script execution (disable popup object explicity):
`document.alert = window.alert = alert = () => {};`

Comment: @kirill.z too bad I need it to run in headless. I use `puppeteer-firefox` instead

Comment: @OysterD3 just try it! I mean browser context the same for JS, so create a helper method to call that script like: `await page.evaluate(document.alert = window.alert = alert = () => {};)` and all! More info related executing at https://dev.to/benjaminmock/executing-javascript-in-the-page-context-of-puppeteer-fp8

Answer (score 0):

Just disable popup. I mean browser context the same for JS, so create a helper method to call the next script:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.alert = window.alert = alert = () => {};)
```